# Porting an aspx website to sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, migration, asp.net

We have a requirement from a client for porting an ASPX website to sharepoint :

Though the site is being served in ASPX there are no form submissions so effectively, they are just static pages without any server side processing required.

However, there is a common header and footer being used.

Here are some of the features being used in the existing site :

- sifr for font substitution (using non standard web fonts)
- flash animations
- javascript and some jquery
- common header and footer for all pages

My question is how feasible is it to port this website to sharepoint ?
Can i use sifr (or flash for that instance) in sharepoint ? or do i have to port it to silverlight ?

What is the general procedure for converting web applications to sharepoint ? Also i came across this http://www.metalogix.net/Products/Website-Migration-Manager-for-SharePoint/ for migration of website to sharepoint.

Can javascript be used in sharepoint ?
How can i have common header and footer in sharepoint documents ?

Pardon my ignorance or any discrepancies in any of my knowledge since i havent worked with any microsoft technologies i would really appreciate some relevant answers from the community here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use flash, javascript and jquery in sharepoint. Keep in mind that sharepoint is built over asp.net.

I never used sifr, but if it is just flash there shouldn't be any problem using it with sharepoint. Anyway, you can start considering using webfonts instead.

Common header an footer pages are also easy to implement with sharepoint as you can use the master pages, wich are exactly for that.

Answer (score 0):

We did something quite similar to that and what we did was place the pages under Layouts and attach them to the master page. This is about 20 mins of work, but it looks like SharePoint. We needed that to integrate an LOB system to become a part of a large MOSS portal